# Comparing variables against a baseline in R random effect mixed models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I am trying to analyse the effect of age and town on F2 value of speakers.

Firstly apologies if this question is really basic, I missed pretty much all of my R tutorials due to the pandemic and having to learn myself, and I am very much a beginner. Any help at all would be hugely appreciated.

My aim was to compare the F2 of older and younger speakers to look and language change. After comparing, it seems there isn't much significance with age, so I now need to look at random effect mixed models to include the town, which does seem to have an effect on F2.

My data includes F2 (value), Town (name), Speaker (name) and age (young/old)

The first model I tried, using lme4, was F2 ~ Age * Town + (1|Speaker), I then used 'fixef' to see the size of the effects and then 'confint(model)' to see the confidence intervals.

However, the way I am doing it means that ‘Town’ is measured against the overall average F2 value, rather
than comparing Towns against a baseline Town. I want to set the contrasts to baseline/treatment so that the effect is comparing the Towns to one of them, so that it will capture the difference and I am not sure how to do that.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Questions about how to do something in R are usually seen as off-topic here. Try https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. lme4 will use treatment contrasts by default. I don't understand "However, the way I am doing it means that ‘Town’ is measured against the overall average F2 value, rather than comparing Towns against a baseline Town."

Comment: What is F2? Can you explain?